# Linker command failed with exit code 1 react native Xcode

Tags: react-native, linker-errors

I am new in react native and integrated push notification for my app after linking all the file and configuration I am regular getting below error:

I used all the steps:
1) Removed build setting > Library paths.
2) Deleted "DerivedData" all the files and clean project and build.

my error is this:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mbsapp-hgygqszwdnjiuogwbarwmtxsmneb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React'
```

and in red :

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please check screenshot here:

[image]